# Abstract Factory in Java - How to extend?

Tags: java, abstract-factory

I use java library, `core`, with `AbstractFactory` responsible for UI components. MyApplication uses core and customizes the UI. Therefore during startup of MyApplication I set MyFactory as an instance of AbstractFactory.

```
class AbstractFactory {
  ...
  public static AbstractFactory getInstance();
  public abstract JButon createButton();
  public abstract JLabel createLabel();
  ...
}

class MyFactory extends AbstractFactory {
   ...
}

MyApplication.startup() {
  AbstractFactory.setInstance(new MyFactory())
}
```

My problem is, that I need to create, for example, JList in MyApplication, but I cannot add `public JList createJList()` in AbstractFactory, because I cannot modify core library.

What shall I do?

**Case One:**
Always call `MyFactory.getMyFactoryInstance()` in MyApplication, new static field.

```
class MyFactory extends AbstractFactory {
   private static MyFactory myInstance = new MyFactory();
   public static getMyFactoryInstance() { return myInstance }
   ...
}
```

**Case Two:**
Always call `MyFactory.getMyFactoryInstance()` in MyApplication, use cast

```
class MyFactory extends AbstractFactory {
   public static MyFactory getMyFactoryInstance() { 
       if (getInstance() instanceOf MyFactory) {
           return (MyFactory) getInstance();
       }
       throw Exception();
   }
   ...
}
```

**Case Three:**
Use Two Factories. For JButtons and JLabels, use AbstractFactory, for JList use SomeOtherFactory.

```
JButton button = AbstractFactory.getInstance().createButton();
JList list = SomeOtherFactory.getInstance.createList();
```

**Case Four:** Something better? I feel I overlooked something.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an abstract subclass of `AbstractFactory` that specifies the `createJList()` method and overwrites the `getInstance()` method which returns the new abstract class type. You can then implement the logic within your MyFactory class and keep to the **principle of programming to interfaces (in this case, abstractions), not implementations**!

Example code:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractFactory extends AbstractFactory {
 //you could implement AbstractFactory's abstract methods here

 public abstract JList createJList();
}

public class MyFactory extends MyAbstractFactory {
 private static MyAbstractFactory instance;

 private MyFactory() {}

 public JList createJList() {
  //implementation of method here
 }
 public static MyAbstractFactory getInstance() {
  if (instance == null) instance = new MyFactory();
  return instance;
 }
}
```

The above example uses **lazy instantiation**, which is great if the code isn't always used and is not used in a multi threaded application. If it is however used in a multi-threaded way I would use the following implementation of `MyFactory` that uses **double-checked locking** to deal with multiple threads.

```
public class MyFactory extends MyAbstractFactory {
 private volatile static MyAbstractFactory instance;

 private MyFactory() {}

 public JList createJList() {
  //implementation of method here
 }
 public static MyAbstractFactory getInstance() {
  if (instance == null) {
   syncronized(MyFactory.class) {
    if (instance == null) instance = new MyFactory();
   }
  }
  return instance;
 }
}
```

With either implementation the usage will remain the same.

Usage:

```
MyAbstractFactory factory = MyFactory.getInstance();
factory.createJList();
```

Comment: How shall I implement the getInstance()? Shall I use cast - maybe unsafe, or shall I introduce new static field of MyFactory type? BTW: I suppose the getInstance() should be static method.

Comment: @ jk_ I have updated my answer to include the getInstance code and all other required segments of code (private constructor, static MyAbstract Factory variable). Please see above.

Comment: I Like the idea with MyAbstractFactory. But got an argument against the solution: there will be two static members: 'instance' of AbstractFactory type (from AbstractFactory) and 'instance' of MyAbstractFactory type (from MyAbstractFactory). And somebody just don't like this idea.

Comment: @jk_ The getInstance method in MyFactory will override the static getInstance method set out in AbstractFactory.

Comment: You cannot use MyFactory.getInstance() because it tights your application with MyFactory. I use MyAbstractFactory so that somebody may "inject" another implementation. And if I have method MyAbstractFactory.getInstance(): MyAbstractFactory, I need private static field instance of MyAbstractFactory type in MyAbstractFactory class and static setter for this field.

Comment: **Lazy initialization** will becomes the hell if you later need to create the instance with a method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need different factories to build different things, have you considered incorporating generics?

```
interface Factory<T> {
  ...
  T create();
  ...
}
```

Just have a typed factory for every type of thing you need to create. For example:

```
class JButtonFactory implements Factory<JButton> {
    public JButton create() {
        return new JButton();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. How can this replace Abstract Factory Pattern? Let's suppose the core library uses these generics, how can I made core to use MyJButton, instead of default JButton?